# Cannot ssh into read-only server (VS Code, remote explorer)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect to a remote linux server per `ssh` using the Remote Explorer extension from Visual Studio Code. However, the user I am using to connect has only read-only rights and therefore cannot create a profile folder in the `.vscode-server` folder that already exists. Apparently, this is necessary for the connection?

```bash
[...]
[13:14:26.642] "install" wrote data to terminal: "************************"
[13:14:26.657] > 
[13:14:27.200] > 6ea66b959d0b: running
[13:14:27.211] > mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/airbyte/.vscode-server/bin/2cyd690cbff1569’
> Creating the server install dir failed...
> : Read-only file system
[...]
[13:14:27.242] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[...]
```

I can connect via shell using `ssh user@ip`. Everything is using the same `config` and `known_hosts` files and ssh keys.

Can anybody tell me how to get around this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was in a READ-ONLY state and had to be rebooted. After this it worked without a problem.